# Unable to create new Android Project in eclipse since 4.1 sdk update

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed the new SDK update since the 4.1 update (windows)

Now, In Eclipse when I try to create a new project I can follow the wizard to the end and when I click the "finish" button i see the new project in the package explorer but now i have the problem:

A) the wizard doesn't close
B) when I click cancel to close it I see a completly empty project, as in ... NOTHING not even the eclipse generated R files.

How to fix it?
I'd really like to create a new project

Comment: It sounds like something's screwy in Eclipse. Have you tried uninstall/reinstall Eclipse and related stuff? I'm presuming you've already rebooted and run the updater again.

Comment: Are you using the Text icon option? There appears to be a bug that prevents projects using the Text icon to be fully generated. I've used both the Image and Clipart options and had success.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to use the text... currently reinstalling eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it really only was the bug in the text option when you create launcher icons.

It is now working because I chose something different.

Comment: this is not the case for me.  no matter what I select, it always does not close the dialog when I select finish and then I have to cancel to a blank project.  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday. Don't know exactly what helped, but restarting Eclipse might have been it. Also, though eclipse doesn't find any updates, choosing "Install new software" and selecting the ADT-Plugin Server (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) installs a couple of new things, so you might wanna try that too.